# how to show different images on different iphone versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to show a different image based on the iphone version? I have a story board of multiple view controllers - each view controller has a separate image that forms its view. How do I show different images based on the iphone version the use is using?

Comment: different iphone version as in ios7, ios8 like this? or device specific?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251 you will be able to identify the iphone versions.

Now according to the device show the image you want to show on the view controller.

The above gist will return the Device name, it will be better if you update the gist and return the name of image, so that you can directly set the image which is returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

I find pretty easy:

```
+ (NSString *) platform{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

+ (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5C";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 6G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini Retina (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (CDMA)";


    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    return platform;
}
```

Taken straight out of UIDeviceHardware.m.

On [GitHub](https://github.com/fahrulazmi/UIDeviceHardware)

This returns `platform` as an NSString. You can then compare the return string using `isEqualToString`.

I don't know why or what images you want to show for which device, but a way to simplify this would be to create an array for each image type, and then add the device models to the respective array, since there are quite a number of devices. For example, creating `imageOneArray` and then storing all devices you want to have for `imageOne`, then `imageTwoArray`, so on, and then iterate through the array checking `isEqualToString`.